# Solve the problem of determining the location in the weather application

Tags: flutter, geolocation, bloc, weather

I am working on defining a project to implement time and its appearance on my site. Another site appears to me in another country and it undertakes by all means to solve the problem, but I do not know what the error is

I tried to change something in geologaiton, but the same error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.